# cannot handle QNetworkAccessManager::finised signal in multithreading

Tags: multithreading, qt, networking

I want to serialize network requests using QNetworkAccessManager. For achieving it i wrote such class:

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>

class Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    struct RequestRecord
    {
        RequestRecord(QString u, int o):url(u),operation(o){}
        QString url;
        int operation;
    };

    std::mutex mutex;
    std::queue<RequestRecord*> requests;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    bool running;
    std::condition_variable cv;

public:
    Client():manager(nullptr){}
    ~Client()
    {
        if(manager)
            delete manager;
    }

    void request_cppreference()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        requests.push(new RequestRecord("http://en.cppreference.com",0));
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void request_qt()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        requests.push(new RequestRecord("http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html",1));
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void process()
    {
        manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;

        connect(manager,&QNetworkAccessManager::finished,[this](QNetworkReply *reply)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            RequestRecord *front = requests.front();
            requests.pop();
            delete front;
            reply->deleteLater();
        });

        running = true;

        while (running)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            cv.wait(lock);

            RequestRecord *front = requests.front();
            manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(front->url)));
        }
    }
};

#endif // CLIENT_H
```

As one can see, there are 2 methods for requesting data from network and method process, which should be called in separate thread.

I'm using this class as follows:

```
Client *client = new Client;    

std::thread thr([client](){
        client->process();
    });

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

client->request_qt();
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
client->request_cppreference();
```

This example illustrate 2 consecutive requests to network from one thread and processing of these request in another. All works fine except my lambda is never called. Requests are sent (checked it using wireshark), but i cannot get replies. What is the cause?

Comment: Its work without lambda slot?

Comment: Perhaps `QNetworkAccessManager` needs a working event loop?

Comment: @Taz742 nope, behavior is the same

Comment: @thuga may be, i'll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @thuga suppose the problem was in event loop. My thread always waiting on cv and thus cannot process events, little hack solve the problem:

```
void process()
    {
        manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;

        connect(manager,&QNetworkAccessManager::finished,[this](QNetworkReply *reply)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            RequestRecord *front = requests.front();
            requests.pop();
            delete front;

            qDebug() << reply->readAll();

            processed = true;
            reply->deleteLater();
        });

        running = true;

        while (running)
        {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                cv.wait(lock);

                if(requests.size() > 0 && processed)
                {
                    RequestRecord *front = requests.front();
                    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(front->url)));
                    processed = false;
                    QtConcurrent::run([this]()
                    {
                        while (running)
                        {
                            cv.notify_one();
                            msleep(10);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        }
    }
};
```

it's not beautiful obvious since it is using 3 threads instead of 2, but it is Qt with this perfect phrase:

> QUrl QNetworkReply::url() const Returns the URL of the content
>   downloaded or uploaded. **Note that the URL may be different from that
>   of the original request.** If the
>   QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute was set in the request, then
>   this function returns the current url that the network API is
>   accessing, i.e the url emitted in the QNetworkReply::redirected
>   signal.